# Rust multiple crates are using different tokio versions

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to build a application to monitor my local weather stations in Rust. I request a API using the `reqwest` crate and write data using the `influxdb_rs` crate. And it seems like that reqwest and influxdb_rs are using different tokio versions according to this error that varies depending on the version I set it to in the Cargo.toml file

`there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime`

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    //...
    let api = netatmo::api::New(oauth).await?;

    let station = api.clone().GetStation(DEVICE_ID_MAC.to_string()).await?;
    let device: Device = station.body.devices[0].to_owned();
    println!("Authenticated as {}", station.body.user.mail);
    println!(
        "Found {} Device Mac: [{}]",
        station.body.devices.len(),
        device.id
    );
    println!("Found {} Modules", device.modules.len());
    for module in device.modules {
        println!(
            "Module Name: {:?} Mac: {} Type: {:?} Battery: {}",
            module.module_name,
            module.id,
            module.data_type.join(","),
            BatteryIndicator(module.battery_percent as i64)
        )
    }
    // let client = influx::authenticate().await.unwrap();
    // Tried to fix it by using the tokio-compat crate but did not work
    let mut rt = Runtime::new()?;
    let client = rt.block_on(async {
        let authentication_handle = tokio::spawn(influx::authenticate());
        let client = authentication_handle.await.unwrap();
        client
    });

    let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_secs(300));
    loop {
        let station = api.clone().GetStation(DEVICE_ID_MAC.to_string()).await?;
        let device: Device = station.body.devices[0].to_owned();
        let mut device_dp = point!("indoor_device")
            .add_field("wifi_status", Value::Integer(device.wifi_status))
            .add_field("co2_level", Value::Integer(device.dashboard_data.co2))
            .add_field("humidity", Value::Integer(device.dashboard_data.humidity))
            .add_field("noise", Value::Integer(device.dashboard_data.noise))
            .add_field("pressure", Value::Float(device.dashboard_data.pressure))
            .add_field(
                "temperature",
                Value::Float(device.dashboard_data.temperature),
            )
            .add_timestamp(Utc::now().timestamp());
        let write_err = client
            .write_point(device_dp, Some(Precision::Minutes), None)
            .await
            .is_err();
        if write_err {
            println!("unable to write point");
        }
```

My attempt to fix this resulted in this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<influxdb_rs::Client, influxdb_rs::Error>>: futures::future::Future` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:54:30
    |
54  |       let client = rt.block_on(async {
    |  _____________________--------_^
    | |                     |
    | |                     required by a bound introduced by this call
55  | |         let authentication_handle = tokio::spawn(influx::authenticate());
56  | |         let client = authentication_handle.await.unwrap();
57  | |         client
58  | |     });
    | |_____^ the trait `futures::future::Future` is not implemented for `impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<influxdb_rs::Client, influxdb_rs::Error>>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `futures::future::Future`:
              &'a mut F
              AssertUnwindSafe<F>
              Box<F>
              futures::future::and_then::AndThen<A, B, F>
              futures::future::catch_unwind::CatchUnwind<F>
              futures::future::either::Either<A, B>
              futures::future::empty::Empty<T, E>
              futures::future::flatten::Flatten<A>
            and 58 others
note: required by a bound in `tokio_compat::runtime::Runtime::block_on`
   --> C:\Users\matte\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-compat-0.1.6\src\runtime\threadpool\mod.rs:425:12
    |
425 |         F: Future01,
    |            ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio_compat::runtime::Runtime::block_on`
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `cargo tree`

Answer (score 0):

Your source code references the [netatmo](https://lib.rs/crates/netatmo-rs) crate, last updated in 2020. It depends on reqwests version 0.9, which, in turn, [depends on tokio 0.1](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest/0.9.24/dependencies), which is incompatible with tokio 1.0. That is likely where the mismatch comes from.

You'll have to either fork and update the netamo crate yourself, or scrap it and implement it yourself.